# Giant Trance 4 2016

Tags: giant

Has anybody tried to fit a fox float X2 in a giant trance 4 2016.Because im trying to buy a new rear shox for my Giant trance

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. ‘Has anybody tried ...?’ questions don’t work well on this site. Can you rewrite your question to ask  ‘What do I need to consider when replacing a rear shock unit ?’

Answer (score 1):

Judging by bike images there is nothing that blocks installing any shock to it.

Just be sure to get the shock of same size.

Or you can even check higher specs of Giant Trace for your model year to see which shocks they use.